# VB6 Select combobox text value based on database data

Tags: combobox, vb6, setvalue

I can't find a way to set a value to the ComboBox object based on the value retrieved from a DB.
When I fill the comboBox, I use this code:

```
Do while Not rs1.EOF
   Cboneighborhood.AddItem rs1!Description
   Cboneighborhood.ItemData(CboBarrio.NewIndex) = rs1!Idneighborhood
Loop
```

When I retrieve data for an employee (Employee table has a field called IdNeighborhood) I want the combobox to set the text value that matches this ID.

I can't use the property

```
Cboneighborhood.Text
```

'cause it's a 2-DropDown List type.

Your help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to iterate through the items like this when you get a `Value`:

```
'Reset to no item.
Cboneighborhood.ListIndex = -1
Dim X As Integer
'Iterate through items.
For X = 0 To Cboneighborhood.ListCount - 1
    'Compare value.
    If Cboneighborhood.ItemData(X) = Value Then
        'Select it and leave loop.
        Cboneighborhood.ListIndex = X
        Exit For
    End If
Next X
```