# VB6 get a value selected in a combobox

Tags: combobox, vb6

I'm building a combobox with the following:

```
Select 1 or 2 seats:
1
2
```

And I need to show 1 or 2 as selected depending on the result of a query.

How can I do that?

I have done so far:

```
SQL = " SELECT numberOfSeats FROM mytable "
SQL = SQL & " WHERE userID ='"
SQL = SQL & txtuserID.Text & "'"
Set auxRes = UAN.OpenResultset(SQL, rdOpenDynamic, rdConcurValues, 0)

cmbNumberOfSeats.Clear
cmbNumberOfSeats.AddItem "Select 1 or 2 seats"
cmbNumberOfSeats.AddItem "1"
cmbNumberOfSeats.AddItem "2"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: See this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422210/vb6-select-combobox-text-value-based-on-database-data?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ListIndex` property of the `ComboBox` control to get / set the index of the selected item. You use it like so:

```
Dim nSelectedIndex As Long

nSelectedIndex = cmbNumberOfSeats.ListIndex

If (nSelectedIndex < 0) Then
    'No selected item in the combo box
Else
    'There's a selected item, handle it
End If
```

To set the selected item:

```
cmbNumberOfSeats.ListIndex = nNewSelectedIndex
```

The index of the first item is `0`; when there's no selection, `ListIndex` returns `-1`.